# How can i make Accordion doesn't close when i click on button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning!
Here's my problem.
I created accordion, all works fine, but when i click on the button inside of 'accordion__content' block, this block automaticly closes, what should i do to prevent this?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

    accordions.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const self = e.currentTarget;
            const control = self.querySelector('.accordion__tittle');
            const content = self.querySelector('.accordion__content');

            content.classList.toggle('open');
            control.classList.toggle('open');

            if (content.classList.contains('open')) {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';

            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            };
        });
    });
    });
```

```html
    <ul class="accordion__list">
              <li class="accordion">
                <button class="accordion__control">
                  <span class="accordion__tittle">
                      Reque insolens in vel?
                  </span>
                </button>
                <div class="accordion__content">

                  <p class="faq__block-text">Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu
                    vidit
                    tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti.
                  </p>
                  <button class="faq__block-button">Go to documentation</button>

                </div>
              <li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: please add code snippet to find out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you click the button you are also clicking the element where you defined  the click event listener. So a quick way to stop this with you current code could be to add click listeners on the buttons and stop the propagation:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    
    buttons.forEach(el => {
    
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log('button click')
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    });
```

See example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

    accordions.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        
        console.log('element click')
            const self = e.currentTarget;
            const control = self.querySelector('.accordion__tittle');
            const content = self.querySelector('.accordion__content');

            content.classList.toggle('open');
            control.classList.toggle('open');

            if (content.classList.contains('open')) {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';

            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            };
        });
    });
    
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    
    buttons.forEach(el => {
    
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log('button click')
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    });
    });
```

```html
<ul class="accordion__list">
              <li class="accordion">
                <button class="accordion__control">
                  <span class="accordion__tittle">
                      Reque insolens in vel?
                  </span>
                </button>
                <div class="accordion__content">

                  <p class="faq__block-text">Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu
                    vidit
                    tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti.
                  </p>
                  <button class="faq__block-button">Go to documentation</button>

                </div>
              <li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I added a little correction, it started working when i wrote the accurate class instead of just 'button': 
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.faq__block-button');